# Filter rows based on multiple condtions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working at to filter/remove rows from a data frame `df` in each group of `id`, if they meet the following rules:

1. the date is `2019-08-01`,
2. the values in both columns `city` and `commerce` are not null.

---

```
   id city commerce      date  price
0   1   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
1   1   bj       ft  2019/8/1      5
2   1  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      6
3   2   bj       ft  2019/7/1      3
4   2   bj       ft  2019/8/1      4
5   2  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      7
6   3   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
7   3   bj       ft  2019/8/1      5
```

The code:

```
df[(df["date"].isin(['2019-08-01'])) & (df[df[['city', 'commerce']].notnull()])]
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

My expected result will like this:

```
   id city commerce      date  price
0   1   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
1   1  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      6
2   2   bj       ft  2019/7/1      3
3   2  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      7
4   3   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
5   3   bj       ft  2019/8/1      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If compare multiple columns need [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per rows or [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test all `True`s per rows:

```
df = df[~(df["date"].isin(['2019/8/1'])) | df[['city', 'commerce']].isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
mask = (df["date"].isin(['2019/8/1'])) & df[['city', 'commerce']].notnull().all(1)
df = df[~mask]
```

---

```
print (df)
   id city commerce      date  price
0   1   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
2   1  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      6
3   2   bj       ft  2019/7/1      3
5   2  NaN      NaN  2019/8/1      7
6   3   bj       ft  2019/7/1      7
```